# Share my WordPress plugin for updating how?

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I have programmed my own WordPress plugin for the first time. I would like to make my plugin available to my customers, but I would also like to release updates to my plugin. How can I do that? How can I release updates to my plugin?

Comment: Do you mean automatic updates without using the public WordPress plugin repository? There are some drop-in frameworks you can use to do that for you: maybe have a look at the code for some premium plugins you already have? I think generally they hook the plugin updates hook or the available updates site transient set and add themselves to the list.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. I have developed a plugin. I want to bring out updates for my plugin to my customers. How can I do that?

Everyone who installs my plugin on their CMS should receive updates from me.

Comment: Then I guess you'll just need to send them the plugin .zip, or a link to download the plugin .zip, for them to install as an update. How did you distribute the plugin in the first place?